# Android studio doesn't start on windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, environment-variables

I bought a new laptop and tried to install Android Studio, but It doesn't start.
I set the right path of "JDK_HOME" and "JAVA_Home" in the environment cariables.

[image]

Checked if the Java.exe doesn't exist in C:\Windows\System32

When trying to start Android Studio it shows the process in the Task Manager and disappears instantly.

[image]

My JDK Version is 1.8.0_121.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME
delete one of them should solve your problem. android studio might got duplicated configuration.
If problem remains remove android studio and reinstall it.